# Serve static files for an URL with dynamic params in node js without any library or framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, xmlhttprequest

I have a little problem here.
I want to serve one static file for "/user/:id" URL with a simple node server.
How is this possible?
Here is my request in client side:

```
document.location.href = `http://localhost:8080/user/${x}`;
```

And this is my request handler:

```
var routeHandler;
if (req.method === 'GET') {
        switch (req.url) {
            case '/user/:id':
                routeHandler = userProvider;
                break;
        }
}

function userProvider(req, res) {
        req.url = 'index.html';
        staticFileHandler(req, res);
}

function staticFileHandler(req, res) {
        fs.readFile('client/' + req.url, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(500);
                res.write(err.name);
                res.end();
            }
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }
```

Is there any way to handle this request only with nodejs not using express or any other libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `req.url` isn't going to be an **exact match** for `case '/user/:id':`, don't use a `switch`.

Use an `if` test using a regular expression instead.

```
if ( req.url.match(/^\/user\/\d+/);
```

Comment: In userProvider function, I change the req.url, but It adds "/user/" at the start of every req.url!!! How can I solve this?